# How do I gain the context I want when using a method from an object in a method of another object?

Tags: javascript, this

First Object and method:

```
objectOne.prototype.getData = function (id, callback) { 
    this._sendRestRequest({
    method: "GET",
    path: /accounts/ + id + "/data"
    }, function (error, body, statusCode) {
       if (error) {
           if (body && body.message) {
               console.error("[ERROR]", statusCode + " Error: " + body.message + " (error code " + body.code + ")");
               return callback(body.message);
           }
           return callback(error);
        }
        if (body && body.trades) {
            callback(null, body.trades);
        } else {
            callback("Unexpected response");
        }
    });
};
```

Second Object and method:

```
function dataManip = function () {
     this.data;
     this.getData = function () {
       if(some condition) {
         objectOne.getData("31313", function (error, data) {
              this.data = data;
      });
}
```

If I were to console.log this.data it would be undefined since this refers to the first object and not the second object.

So I've been trying apply, bind, and call; however, I can't seem to get it to work so that "this" refers to dataManip and not ObjectOne.  What is the best way to gain the context I need?

EDIT: Using bind, apply, and call causes an error since "this" is used inside the first object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `this` to callback, like so

```
 objectOne.getData("31313", function (error, data) {
    this.data = data;
 }.bind(this));
```